# hide div when printing maichimp in firefox

Tags: printing, stylesheet, mailchimp

We make newsletters using the mailchimp service for a customer, now our customer would like to  print the webversion of the mailings, but without the mailchimp top bar (#awesomebar).
Is there a plugin or something for firefox or chrome that can prevent an div from printing and that is easy to use for a non-technical person? So firebug is not an option.

I allready tried to contact mailchimp about it, but they won't change the print css.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just disable the awesomebar in the first place?

If not, just use some custom CSS in your template.  Add the class `noprint` to any elements they don't want printed, and then in your custom CSS, add below:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">

.noPrint, #awesomebar {
     display:none !important;
}

</style>
```

If this doesn't "exactly" work for you, hopefully you can use it as a starting point. The `media="print"` tag only applies when the browser goes to print - it doesn't affect the display of the page normally.